# textbox width issue-- IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to set the width 100% on text box but it stretches out the container.. I have checked some questions of the similar kind but there seems no explanation as to why the problem happens.. I know to manually set the properties but I need to find out why this happens. and I am must do it using the 100% property value..

```
   <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="border:1px solid gray;">
            <input type="text" style="width: 100%;"  id="title"/>

        </div>

    <div>
    <a href="#" id="postfile" style="float:left;">Post</a><span style="display:none;  border:1px solid #ee1100; margin-left:10px; color:#cc1100" id="errormessage"></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: are you using a _reset stylesheet_, if not try that

Comment: To answer this, I would need more context ie. the entire HTML document. Ideally you should set the width of the container explicitly to control the % width of its children but I understand if this is not a viable approach.

Comment: The container doesn't have a width specified. Can you provide more context?

Comment: It seems there are more things that you have not mentioned

Comment: This is the asp.net form..

Comment: specifying the width on the container div does not change anything.. the issue persists still...

Comment: make the `border:none` of the input.

Comment: whoever is the downvoter, d*** comment when downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Box sizing on your input

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"  id="title"/>
```

Also the most cross browser way is :

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;"  id="title"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQXXh/

Comment: there's a fiddle, check it out

Comment: Thank you Omid.. Can you explain why is this.. and what is the box-sizing doing

Comment: The box-sizing property allows you to define certain elements to fit an area in a certain way. Just look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 3):

Add `box-sizing:border-box`. The reason it's too wide is because you currently have the content being set to 100% width, but the padding and border are added on.

Comment: I belive you also will have to add `padding-right: 2px;` to the container div as the sum of horisontal borderwidth of the input element (left+right) is 2px.

Answer (score 0):

The default border styling of an `<input>` in `IE` makes it goes outside container div. 
Logically input is 100% wide but the default border adds the extra width to it.
You can try it adding `border:10px solid green;` to you `<input>` in any browser.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%; border:10px solid green;"  id="title"/>
```

It will make you input goes outside the container div. So when you apply `border:0` to `<input>` like:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%; border:0;"  id="title"/>
```

It will be fit in container. I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...as suggested by Kolink, the margin,border and padding are not zero for the text box.So it spans out on 100% width. Thus by using box-sizing:border-box any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height